Calculating Operational space inertia matrix in pydrake
I am implementing a swing leg controller for a quadruped which uses the following equation for computing torques:

I need to calculate the operational space inertia matrix (the Delta_i term) to implement this. Is there a simple function for doing this in Pydrake?
Currently, I am doing it with the following code:
J_leg = self.plant.CalcJacobianTranslationalVelocity(
            self.plant_context,
            JacobianWrtVariable.kV,
            self.plant.GetFrameByName(curr_foot),
            np.zeros(3),
            self.plant.world_frame(),
            self.plant.world_frame()
        )

# Calculate J.T @ Operational Space Inertia Matrix
M = self.plant.CalcMassMatrixViaInverseDynamics(self.plant_context)
J_T_Delta_i = M @ np.linalg.inv(J_leg)

I am curious to know if I can make this computation more efficient.
